# Android NDK sample build error linux

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, android-ndk

Hello I am new to Android and I am trying to build the hello-jni sample that is included in the NDK but I get the error below, any idea how to fix it?

> 15:57:10 **** Build of configuration Default for project HelloJni ****
>   /media/Project/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20131030/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20131030/android-ndk-r9c/ndk-build
>   all  Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-19 is larger than
>   android:minSdkVersion 3 in ./AndroidManifest.xml     [armeabi-v7a]
>   Compile thumb  : hello-jni <= hello-jni.c arm-linux-androideabi-gcc:
>   error trying to exec
>   '/media/Project/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20131030/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20131030/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/as':
>   execv: Exec format error make: ***
>   [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/hello-jni/hello-jni.o] Error 1
>
> 15:57:10 Build Finished (took 230ms)

This is what I am using:

- Ubuntu 10.04.4
- ADT bundle for linux (v22.3.0-887826)
- NDK r9c

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you on a 64-bit system?  If so, you likely need the 32-bit compatibility package to run the toolchain.  An "Exec format error" usually indicates you are trying to run a binary built for a different ABI from that of your system.

Comment: I am not sure how to check if I have 32-bit or 64-bit but `uname -m` returned _i686_ which I think means 32-bit. I downloaded the following files from android developer site: _adt-bundle-linux-x86-20131030.zip_ and _android-ndk-r9c-linux-x86.tar.tar_. I unpacked them on a windows machine before moving them over to my ubuntu VM because it is a bit slow, I hope that does not matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WARNING is correct, and should be ignored.

Regarding the gcc error, you probably have a problem with installation of NDK. How did you unpack it? Check

```
ls -l /media/Project/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20131030/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20131030/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/as
```

This should be a symbolic link to `../../bin/arm-linux-androideabi-as`, and both should have executable permissions.

Comment: I executed the ls command and got the following output:
`-rwxrwxrwx 1 ccs ccs 34 2013-10-09 02:53 /media/Project/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20131030/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20131030/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/as`

I checked the as-file, in a text editor, located in the bin folder and it said `../../bin/arm-linux-androideabi-as`. Both the as-file and arm-linux-androideabi-as file had _Allow executing file as program_ checked. This is correct? I unpacked the NDK on a x64 Win7 machine using 7-zip before I moved it to my ubuntu VM.

Comment: You should unpack the [android-ndk-r9c-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2](http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r9c-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2) in Ubuntu, and make sure that the symbolic links are preserved.

Comment: Ok I will try that, but isn't x86_64 for 64-bit machines? See the comment in my first post. I downloaded the other NDK file (32-bit).

Comment: Yes, you should use the correct bitness version of NDK. Check `uname -a` in your VM to decide which.

Comment: Thank you very much, unpacking directly in Ubuntu solved the problem. I noticed that the symbolic links were like text-files in the package that was unpacked in Windows.