# Error compiling with Android NDK

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I downloaded the Android NDK, I've also got the SDK, everything is set up in Eclipse using the ADT plugin. (I've also got Android Studio and I'm getting the same error)

The first error I got was

```
arm-linux-androideabi/bin/as': execv: Exec format error
```

I fixed that by creating a sym link to darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-as / as advised here

[Android NDK sample build error linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21434819/android-ndk-sample-build-error-linux)

now I'm getting a similar error i686-linux-android/bin/as': execv: Exec format error, I've tried a sym link to the same place but it didn't work, this is the full build error. Do I just need another sym link?

```
i686-linux-android-g++: error trying to exec '/Developer/android-ndk-r9b-darwin-x86_64/android-ndk-r9b/toolchains/x86-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.8/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin/as': execv: Exec format error
```

Comment: Are you in fact using a 64-bit Intel Mac?  What exact symlink did you create?  What is the output of `file /Developer/android-ndk-r9b-darwin-x86_64/android-ndk-r9b/toolchains/x86-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.8/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin/as` run from a command-line?

Comment: the processor name is intel core 2 duo which is 64 bit, the sym link i created was sudo ln -s /Developer/android-ndk-r9b-darwin-x86_64/android-ndk-r9b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-as /Developer/android-ndk-r9b-darwin-x86_64/android-ndk-r9b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/as, and there is no output of that file run from the command line, it just hangs.

Comment: Did you just copy and paste the 'file' command from the Stack Overflow web-page?  The comment formatting seems to have inserted special characters into both of our pathnames (in mine, between "pre" and "built" , for example, and in yours in "arm-linux-an" <special chars> "droid".  Make sure those are not in the 'file' command.  If 'file' really does hang, that could be a symptom of some kind of disk problem.  Are these files on your main local disk, and is that disk OK?  (Maybe verify with Disk Utility)

Comment: I initially copy pasted but it didn't work. so I went into the directly where the as file was then ran it, that's when it hung. Surely if I'm running this 32 bit executable on 64 bits then it's going to have unexpected results? Or would it display an error? The files are on my main disk. Just to be clear, the 2nd symlink I tried with this 2nd compiler error, involving i686-linux-android/bin/as is no longer there, I deleted as it didn't fix anything, it just caused new compiler errors.

Comment: 'file' is a command-line utility which will tell you the file type of the file located at the path you provide as the first argument.  That is what I was looking for.  If you simply run 'as' from the command-line with no arguments it will try to read input from standard in, so the "hang" you see is expected behavior.  The execv error is unusual.  The output of the 'file' command may or may not help diagnose it.

Comment: oh I see, I just tried it again, the output was just 'empty'